# What are the "Mystery Trading Cards"?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

I was in the Steam Market, looking for cheap things to buy/sell as usual, when I noticed [this.](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/753/Mystery%20%28Trading%20Card%29) A "Mystery Trading Card"?

The description is "This card is very mysterious. Very, very mysterious. The kind of mysterious card you might want to hold on to." **Will there be some sort of reward if you have this card later?**

Comment: Buy it and find out!  =P

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about shopping recommendations :-P

Comment: @Zommuter Don't agree on that it's about shopping rec. Mystery needs to be solved!

Comment: Maybe I should have chosen "Questions about unreleased or illegal content are off topic on Arqade. We only support questions about games available to the general public through legitimate means." instead - this question is pure speculation until Steam unveils this "mystery"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for speculation about the future.

Comment: The last part, `More importantly, will it be worth more later?` is unanswerable.  The rest, though, I think is something we can help with.

Comment: Oh man, Valve are just generating money out of thin air now. They're not even being subtle about it - when you purchase one of the mystery cards from the market, you incur a 10% "**mysterious fee**" on top of the usual 5%. That's actually what they call it.

Comment: @lunboks Wait, are you serious, or joking?

Comment: In addition to the 5% Valve fee, there's always a 10% fee on the cards, Portal 2 fee for Portal 2 cards, Half Life 2 fee for Half Life 2 cards, Mysterious fee for Mysterious cards etc.

Comment: I have re-worded the question to be more "on topic."

Comment: FWIW, they're likely going to be used in the upcoming sale. There's a set of 10 different Mystery Cards, plus a foil set, so, you know, gotta catch 'em all.

Comment: Here you can find information about how to distinguish different mystery cards ;) http://steamdb.info/blog/20/ Also I think topic is on subject, steam becomes a meta-game, but still a game ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On July 12th 2013, the Mystery cards turned into [Summer Getaway Trading Cards](http://store.steampowered.com/promotion/summerfaq/).

> Starting July 3rd, crafting a game badge earned you a "mystery card" rather than a coupon. **These mystery cards are now Summer Getaway cards.** So if you crafted a badge in the last week, you're already ahead of the game. During the sale, each game badge you craft will get you a Summer Getaway trading card.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody seems to know what these do yet.  You get them for crafting badges, in place of the typical random coupon.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a guess, as no one knows for sure what mystery cards mean, but:

*Will there be some sort of reward if you have this card later?*

Yes, probably something to do with Summer Sale, which will begin any day now.

*Will it be worth more later?*

No. It's a simple law of supply and demand - the more of these cards are on the market, the less they are worth. Price has already dropped from 2,5 to 1,05 Euro.

Only if Steam suddenly stopped mystery card drops (limited supply) and then made them really worth your while (increased demand), then the price would soar. But that's a slim chance, personally I'd bet on the first option, that the price will gradually drop.

Comment: Thanks, but what would cause you to think that it is related to the Summer Sale, besides how it has appeared right before the Sale?

Comment: Nothing else besides the timing. It makes sense, doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah, I guess it does.